# Consumer Producer conditional wait C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to solve Producer/Consumer problem using pthreads and I'm kinda stuck on the implementation.

Multiple producers opens a file and read line by line and put those lines in a fixed buffer. If the buffer is full each producer waits and signals the consumer which reads from the buffer and writes to file..it does this until every line has been read from the file.

```
char *buffer[20]; //shared buffer
void* Producer(void* args){
    struct Data *data = (struct Data*) args;

    FILE* fp;
    char buf[file_buffer];

    if ((fp = fopen(data->file_name, "r")) == NULL)
    { /* Open source file. */
        perror("Couldn't open file.");
        exit(0);
}

    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* protect buffer */
    while (isFUll())               /* If the buffer is full wait */
        pthread_cond_wait(&condp, &the_mutex);
    //read and add to buffer
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
    {
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // each line from file
        //add line to buffer here
    }

    pthread_cond_signal(&condc);    /* wake up consumer */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);   /* release the buffer */
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Does the producer continue reading from where it left off if the buffer is full but the reading isn't complete from the file? If n

Comment: is this an assignment? If not, this problem does not sound very conducive to multi-threaded solution to me.

Comment: yeah it's an assignment

Comment: just so I'm clear, you have multiple producers reading from a single file, and a single consumer writing that data to a single file?

Comment: Nah. each producer reads a single file and there are multiple consumers too. It's like one producer tied with one consumer.

Comment: The consumers write to a single file tho.

Comment: For the one actual question there, you would need to talk to the person who wrote your requirements. In this case, your professor. If he doesn't care, then you do what you think would give the best performance keeping in mind that you won't have infinite memory.

Comment: A typical "circular buffer" has an input pointer or index and output pointer or index. As long as input pointer not equal output pointer, the producer can keep writing while the consumer is reading within the same buffer. Each thread manages its own index or pointer, resetting to zero when they get to the end. The consumer should wait whenever  `output==input`, except when the producer indicates that input is pointing to last element that can be retrieved from the source (ie; EOF).